# how to use a variable outside of class which is inside a function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

```
       import UIKit
       import CoreData

       var i = 9
       var b = Calculate // i want to use that 'Calculate' variable here and same for other 'percentage' var 

       class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {........
              .....................
               ......................
               ..................
               var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Entity")
                request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
               // request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: " = %@", txt2.text!)
                request.predicate = predicate

                let results:NSArray = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]
                //request.predicate = predicate


                if (results.count > 0){
                    var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
                    txt1.text = res.valueForKey("txt1") as! String
                    //.text = res.valueForKey("password") as! String

                    print("atendence = \(results.count)")

                    print("percentage = \(100*results.count/30)")
                    print(results.count)

                    var calculate = 100*results.count/30

                    var percentage = Float(calculate)




                    txt4.text = "\(percentage)%"
                    txt2.text = "\(results.count)"
                    txt3.text = "\(100*results.count/30)"

              ................................
                .......................}
```

i want to use this two variables var percentage and var calculate outside of Viewcontrollerclass
and sorry if not asking properly or if am not able to clarify my question ,  because am totally new here

Comment: outside in the sense, where do you wan to use. In methods inside the view controller or other view controllers?

Comment: see my comment on my code on line no. 4 @PK20

Comment: on same viewController but outside the class right after import uikit and import CoreData @PK20

Comment: assign  b =  calculate right after var calculate = 100*results.count/30 line

Comment: @johnykumar i want to use that var b in another Swift file thats why am declaring that outside the class ! thanks for suggestion

Comment: declare the variable in your header file. something like `@property (nonatomic, retain) String* b;` and `@synthesize b` in your .m file to use

Comment: you can user directly b variable in another file.you have declared variable as global which canbe fetch from any other class

Comment: hey done with property (nonatomic, retain) String* b; but am not getting how do that synthesize b thing @PK20

Comment: @johnykumar i tried as you suggested but its not working when i tried to use that variable in my another swift file it throwing an error 'use of unresolved 'b''

Comment: that file is of swift or objective-C ?where you are accessing b variable

Comment: its a swift file @johnykumar

Comment: i have tried i am able to access that b variable in another swift file.can you put your code or image where you are accessing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96129/discussion-between-abhinaman-abhi-and-johny-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Don't do that.**

All data is supposed to be encapsulated.
Use a struct with static variables outside a class.

```
struct Global {
  static var i = 9
  static var calculate : Float = 0.0
}
```

Access the variable with

```
let x = Global.calculate
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a shared instance like follows for the variables you want to access globally.

```
import UIKit

class globalVariables {
    class var sharedInstance: globalVariables {
        struct Static {
            static var instance: globalVariables?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = globalVariables()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    var a: String = ""
    var b: String = ""
}
```

And in any viewControllers, you can access it like

```
globalVariables.sharedInstance.a 
globalVariables.sharedInstance.b
```